Node.js - Single executable applications: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
I have an issue when running a node.js application (on Windows 10) as a single executable application following this documentation.
This error occurs:
.\main.exe
(node:12216) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `main --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
main.js:28
import * as apiKeysHandler from "./helpers/apiKeysHandler.js";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:77:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:20)
    at embedderRunCjs (node:internal/util/embedding:19:27)
    at node:internal/main/embedding:18:8

Node.js v20.11.0

The content of sea-config.json was:
{
    "main": "main.js",
    "output": "sea-prep.blob"
}

I know that I need to modify my package.json file to load a ES module (this is also a warning in the output I listed above). Therefore my package.json looks like:
{
  "main": "main.js",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "sync-request": "^6.1.0"
  }
}

I already tried to add "type": "module" into my sea-config.json but this changed nothing.
When I run node.exe with my main.js on command line there is no error and my application is running fine. When I run main.exe in the same directory the error listed above occurs.
Can anyone tell me my mistake please? Thanks!

Update 13.05.2024
@sychordCoder Thanks for responding. Here is my folder structure:
root

main.js
helpers

apiKeysHandler.js


.gitignore
package.json
package-lock.json


Can you provide the folder structure of the project from the root?

I extended my question with the folder structure.

Easiest might be to rename your .js files to .mjs files.
